# pass errors between methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

I have 2 methods - GET and POST. GET method fills form, POST method adds record to DB. It works. But sometimes POST method gets an error (invalid data, which can't be checked on client side etc) and I call GET method again.

GET Method:

```
public ActionResult VacancyForm(int? ID, VacancyFormViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        model = new VacancyFormViewModel();
```

POST Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VacancyForm(VacancyFormViewModel model)
{
    if (surgeonSelected == null) // error case
    {
        return VacancyForm(null, model);
    }
```

Question - how to pass all errors from post to get?

Comment: You don't! Add the error to `ModelState` and return the view - `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "your error message"); return View(model);`  - do not call the GET method

Answer (score 0):

You  can use ModelState's `AddModelError` method to add them server-side in your controller as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VacancyForm(VacancyFormViewModel model)
{

    if (surgeonSelected == null) // error case
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("SurgeonSelected ", "An error has occurred");
        return VacancyForm(model);
    }
}
```

This can be displayed out via:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("SurgeonSelected ")
```

If you are using strongly typed views you could use:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SurgeonSelected )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as argument:

```
   public ActionResult VacancyForm(int? ID, VacancyFormViewModel model, string errorMessage = null)
   {
      if(errorMessage != null)
          ModeState.AddModelError("", errorMessage);

   }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VacancyForm(VacancyFormViewModel model)
{

    if (surgeonSelected == null) // error case
    {
        string error = "You error message";
        return VacancyForm(null, model, error);
    }
}
```